# Xcode Getting a Consistent Documents Directory Path

Tags: ios, xcode, nsfilemanager

I've looked through the Apple documentation on this point and other questions here, but cannot find a means of getting a consistent path to the documents directory.

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *urls = [fm URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];

NSURL *directory = [urls lastObject];
```

This produces a different path each time due to one component.

Example:

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/**CA708CF5-0E1B-414D-A795-31A8BB884BA5**/Documents

Next run:

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/**2C96E341-85EF-485D-AC19-F8844B0880C3**/Documents

I realize I need some kind of relative path here but I cannot figure out how to get it.  How can I get to the Documents directory consistently to both write and read a file my app will produce?

Comment: You may get a different path each time you run the app (especially during development. This is normal. But the contents are copied from the old path to the new path each time so everything should work just fine as long as you don't persist full paths.

Comment: I am using an actual device.  When I save a dictionary using the path name found from the code above and then go to retrieve it using the path information above, there is no data.  I assumed this was due to the changing paths, but you are saying that shouldn't be the case?

Comment: Each time you build and deploy, the data should get copied from the old location to the new location. This assumes you are not deleting the app between each build.

Comment: Thank you.  The issue then must be with the write and not the path.  The path would seem to be a red herring...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path is determined on installation. Each time you run your app in the simulator, it will be removed and reinstalled. Hence the differernt path. So you don't need to worry about this.

Comment: I am not running it on the simulator though, I am running it on an actual device.  If the path changes how can I get to the file I wrote to in session 1 when I am now in session 2?  I am using the code above to get the path each time and since the path changes the file isn't there.